# git project based on active project

Tags: git, github

We have a white labelled site that requires customization for our various clients.

Is it possible to reference a base git project, receive any and all updates into client specific git project while having a separate project for each client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sharing change between an "upstream" project and many clients is what distributed version control systems like Git are for. Each client can clone the parent repository and begin introducing commits local to that client's clone. The parent project can continue to add change, and each client can `pull` that change into their own repository.

I'd caution you that this is not a strong case for version control, you shouldn't be trying to store divergent changes across forks. You should share the "core" functionality through whatever library-distribution means your language provides to create a stronger wall between shared and client-specific functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The project is a vue.js project -- not sure how to implement a massive white labelled (in development) vue.js project that can be integrated into other projects.